# Update field inside object in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update a object inside another but when the object is updated replace all information.

Structure

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : {type: String, unique: true},
        password     : String
    }
    name: String
});
```

before be updated

user

```
{
    name = 'foo',
    local {
        email: "foo@foo.com",
        password: "foopass"
    }
}
```

after be updated

```
{
    name = 'foo',
    local {
        email: "foo@foo.com"
    }
}
```

this is my query:

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res) {

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $set: { name: req.body.name, local: {email: req.body.email} }
    }, { upsert: true },
    function(err, obj) {
        return res.json(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `$set: { name: req.body.name, "local.email": req.body.email }` instead of `$set: { name: req.body.name, local: {email: req.body.email} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dot notation in the `$set` key to target just the `email` property of `local` instead of updating the whole `local` object:

```
router.put('/:id', function(req, res) {

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        $set: { name: req.body.name, 'local.email': req.body.email }
    }, { upsert: true },
    function(err, obj) {
        return res.json(true);
    });
});
```